# How to get the Microsoft Teams active meeting window with AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-teams

In the Microsoft Teams Windows Client I would like to be able to identify with AutoHotkey the current active meeting window.
Consider that you can have several Teams window opened (popped-out chats, main window, several meeting windows with some on hold,...)

(Background: I want to do this to be able to send meeting specific actions hotkeys.)

Comment: Would you mind if I re-ask this question and put a bounty on it for if they can automatically determine which window is the correct meeting window without user input? I've also wanted something that can identify which window is the correct meeting window given that all of the stats in Window Spy are either empty, useless, or the same as the main Teams Window. Also, I think that the popped-out chat and meeting windows are only for people that have turned on MS Teams Beta, but it might have been also added to the main release earlier this year for all I know.

Comment: @Spyre Popout chat was released a long time ago (around May 2020 according a quick googling) I wouldn't like to duplicate the question for a bounty. Can't you place a bounty on mine?

Comment: I can't for some reason; I literally do not have the "Start a Bounty" button for some reason on this page. If I go to any other question though, even one with an accepted answer, it will show me the button.

Comment: @Spyre https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54726/missing-start-a-bounty-link-on-stackoverflow  question must be 2 days old

Comment: I was not aware of that, I'll start it since the button has now appeared for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current implementation based on UIAutomation library - see https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2022/07/ahk-get-teams-meeting-win.html

Gist code https://gist.github.com/tdalon/5b3304559852d1d1942b7f1566de2a0c

Answer (score 2):

I have come to another approach based on FindText to exclude any user prompt.
It check in the Teams windows if a UI Element like Leave and Resume are available to 100% exclude the wrong window.

See detailed explanation in this post: https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2021/04/ahk-get-teams-meeting-window.html
with screencast.
And here the code in gist: https://gist.github.com/tdalon/d376a2ac395a41c5453904222cbcb529

Extract below:

```
Teams_GetMeetingWindow(useFindText:="" , restore := True){
; See implementation explanations here: 
;   https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2021/04/ahk-get-teams-meeting-window.html
;   https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/10/get-teams-window-ahk.html

If (useFindText="")
    useFindText := PowerTools_GetParam("TeamsMeetingWinUseFindText") ; Default 1

If (useFindText) {
    If (restore)
        WinGet, curWinId, ID, A
    ResumeText:="|<>*138$51.zzzzzzzzw3zzzzzzzUDzzzzzzwtzzzzzzzbA64NU1kQ1423A04FUtUQNa8aAX0EXAlY1a9zUNaAbwt4Y0AlYHb4461aAkTzzzzzzzzU" ; FindText for Resume
    LeaveText:="|<>*168$66.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzDzzzzzy01zzDzzzzzs00TzDzzzzzk00DzDkkFW3U7k7zDUG9YFUDk7zD6T9YlUTs7zD0E841kTs7zD7nAAzszwDz022AAHzzzzz0UECS3zzzzzzzzzzzU"
}

WinGet, Win, List, ahk_exe Teams.exe
TeamsMainWinId := Teams_GetMainWindow()
TeamsMeetingWinId := PowerTools_RegRead("TeamsMeetingWinId")
WinCount := 0
Select := 0


Loop %Win% {
    WinId := Win%A_Index%
    If (WinId = TeamsMainWinId) { ; Exclude Main Teams Window 
        ;WinGetTitle, Title, % "ahk_id " WinId
        ;MsgBox %Title%
        Continue
    }
    WinGetTitle, Title, % "ahk_id " WinId  
    
    IfEqual, Title,, Continue
    Title := StrReplace(Title," | Microsoft Teams","")
    If RegExMatch(Title,"^[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*,[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*$") or RegExMatch(Title,"^[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*,[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*\([^\s\(\)]*\)$") ; Exclude windows with , in the title (Popped-out 1-1 chat) and max two words before , Name, Firstname               
        Continue
    
    If RegExMatch(Title,"^Microsoft Teams Call in progress*") or RegExMatch(Title,"^Microsoft Teams Notification*") or RegExMatch(Title,"^Screen sharing toolbar*")
        Continue
    
    If (useFindText) {
        ; Exclude window with no Leave element
        WinActivate, ahk_id %WinId%
        If !(ok:=FindText(,,,, 0, 0, LeaveText,,0)) {
            Continue
        } 
        
        ; Final check - exclude window with Resume element = On hold meetings
        If (ok:=FindText(,,,, 0, 0, ResumeText,,0)) {
            Continue
        } 
    }
        
    WinList .= ( (WinList<>"") ? "|" : "" ) Title "  {" WinId "}"
    WinCount++

    ; Select by default last meeting window used
    If WinId = %TeamsMeetingWinId% 
        Select := WinCount  
} ; End Loop

If (WinCount = 0)
    return
If (WinCount = 1) { ; only one other window
    RegExMatch(WinList,"\{([^}]*)\}$",WinId)
    TeamsMeetingWinId := WinId1
    PowerTools_RegWrite("TeamsMeetingWinId",TeamsMeetingWinId)
    return TeamsMeetingWinId
}

If (restore)
    WinActivate, ahk_id %curWinId%

LB := WinListBox("Teams: Meeting Window", "Select your current Teams Meeting Window:" , WinList, Select)
RegExMatch(LB,"\{([^}]*)\}$",WinId)
TeamsMeetingWinId := WinId1
PowerTools_RegWrite("TeamsMeetingWinId",TeamsMeetingWinId)
return TeamsMeetingWinId

} ; eofun
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find it out by the Window Title, but Teams does not name Meeting windows in a particular way.

I could find with AccViewer that the Main Team Window has its name ending with "| Microsoft Teams, Main Window". So at least I can exclude this one.

[Here](https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/10/get-teams-window-ahk.html) is an old solution I have come to.
But it requires the user to confirm which window is the current meeting window (if not obvious).

The code can be found in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/tdalon/87590637e43479c90f355be90aff3842#file-teams_getmeetingwindow-ahk